# error: "this.jc is not a function" (main.js line 853)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

My map is acting strangely.  The table that lists data about each marker does not highlight correctly, and the tablabels variable is giving some strange results. Some of my markers are gone and firebug is giving me an error that says "this.jc is not a function" and refers me to main.js line 853.  This error really snuck up on me and I'm not even sure where to begin troubleshooting it.  Any ideas?  Has anyone seen anything like this?

Okay, after a suggestion to check events, I checked the myclick() function:

```
function myclick(i) {
      GEvent.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
    }
```

firebug says that "a" is undefined in main.js line 140 in regards to this function

Here's additional code, it might help

```
    //Highlights rows of all nested wells with same id as marker if it is a well marker
  GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);

    //only highlight table for wells
    //markers with id = 2 are static wells, otherwise
    //we skip table highlighting
    if(marker.id==2)
    {
        var Table = document.getElementById("myTable3");
        var rows = Table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var f;
        for(f=0;f<rows.length;f++)
        {
            if(rows[f].id==marker.name)
                rows[f].className="selected";
            else
                rows[f].className="unselected"
        }
    }

    });

  //add marker, icon, and popup to global arrays
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  gmarkers[i] = marker;
  htmls[i] = popup_html;
  icons[i] = icon;
  /*Add data to each sidebar depending on id: 0=stream flow station, 1=rain gage, 2=well */
  if(id==0)
  {
      side_bar_html[0] += '<tr><td><a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')"  onmouseover="gmarkers['+i+'].blink(true,250)" onmouseout="gmarkers['+i+'].blink(false,0)">' + name + '</a><br></td>';
      side_bar_html[0] += '<td class="col1" align="center">' + number + '</td>' ;
      side_bar_html[0] += '<td class="col1" align="center">' + data2 + " " + ft +'</td>' ;
      side_bar_html[0] += '<td class="col1" align="center">' + update + '</td>';
      side_bar_html[0] += '<td class="col1" align="center"><a href=' + link + '>NWIS link</td></tr>' ;



  }
  if(id==2)
  {

     side_bar_html[2] += '<tr id=' + z + '><td><a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')"  onmouseover="gmarkers['+i+'].blink(true,250)" onmouseout="gmarkers['+i+'].blink(false,0)">' + number + '</a><br></td>'; 
     side_bar_html[2] += '<td class="col1" align="right">' + name + '</td>';
     side_bar_html[2] += '<td class="col1" align="right">' + data2 + '</td>';
     side_bar_html[2] += '<td class="col1" align="center">' + update + '</td>';
     side_bar_html[2] += '<td class="col1" align="center"><a href=' + link + '>NWIS Link</td></tr>' ;

     z++;
  }

  map.addOverlay(marker);
  ++i;

}
```

i just checked aspects of my marker variables.  It appears that the ones that have gone missing are also duplicating certain content.  Could this have something to do with the DupFlag variable?

Comment: hard to tell without more detail - are you using any event listeners with your map - if so, check the callback functions you're passing to the addListener call to make sure they're valid functions

Comment: fyi, I didn't write this code. I've been asked to add to it.  But yes, there is an event where if you click on the marker or the items in the table, a pop up table appears with data about the marker.  Those are not functioning properly.

Comment: can you post the relevant callback code? my best guess is you have a problem with the context of this in the callback

Comment: hmm, don't see anything that could be causing any issues with context there

Comment: You are using the deprecated [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference).  From the documentation "he Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until May 19, 2013.".  New development in that API is discouraged, you should port the application to the Google Maps API v3.

Comment: if I update to version 3, do you think this error will be fixed?

Comment: I don't know, but it doesn't make sense to me to spend time on fixing something that you will have to port to v3 in less than an month and a half.  Port it to v3, fix any problems you find and you won't have to port it again until Google deprecates v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe how simple this was to fix.  I had accidentally deleted a line of code:

```
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

It was supposed to be after the loop that added data to the sidebar